# Foundation 6 - columns are not float left?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have list of items, i put in columns like this

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
   <img src="img.png" />
   <p>Title</p>
   <p>Desc</p>
   <a href="#">abc</a>
</div>
```

But, A few of them are not float left, although i set for them :

```
float : left !important;
```

Comment: Can you paste complete code?

Answer (score 1):

`.column, .columns` in foundation are floated to left by default.
If you encounter some grid issues then you better need to read the docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html) and make sure you call the right css and js scripts. Script source can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation). Select one that is right for you.

Code:

```
<div class="small-6 columns">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
     <p>Title</p>
     <p>Desc</p>
     <a href="#">abc</a>
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
     <p>Title</p>
     <p>Desc</p>
     <a href="#">abc</a>
  </div>
```

Hope this would help.